# MySQL summing totals by state by year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been playing around with this for what seems like hours and I can't get the results I want. Here is the query I am having trouble with:

```
    SELECT year.year, dstate,
   (SELECT sum(amount) FROM gift 
      WHERE year.year = gift.year 
      AND gift.donorno = donor.donorno)
    FROM donor, gift, year
      WHERE year.year = gift.year 
      AND gift.donorno = donor.donorno;
```

This seems redundant. Anyway, I am trying display the total donations (gift.amount) for each state by year.

```
ex.
1999 GA 500 (donorno 1 from GA donated 200 and donorno 2 from GA donated 300)
1999 FL 400
2000 GA 600
2000 FL 500
...
```

To clarify donors can be from the same state but I am trying to total the gift amounts for that state for the year it is donated.
Any advice is appreciated. I feel like the answer is right in front of me.

Here is a picture of tables for reference:
[image: table diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple join & aggregation problem.

```
SELECT y.year, d.state, SUM(g.amount) AS total
FROM gift AS g
INNER JOIN year AS y ON y.year=g.year
INNER JOIN donor AS d ON d.donorno=g.donorno
GROUP BY y.year, d.state
```

You don't need the sub-query in your SELECT clause in order to get the total amount. You can sum it by grouping. (I think the `GROUP BY` clause is what you're missing. I recommend reading up on it.) What you've done is called a correlated sub-query and it is going to be very slow over large data sets because it has to be calculated row-by-row instead of as a set operation.

Also, please don't use the old style comma join syntax. Instead use the explicit join syntax as shown above. It is much clearer and will help avoid accidental Cartesian products.

Comment: Thank you. As you can probably tell I am new to SQL and currently taking an introductory course. I am not exactly sure what you mean by "old style comma syntax". I will also have to read up on how to use the INNER JOIN keyword. Some of my experimenting had me using the GROUP BY but I didn't know you could use it with multiple columns. Obviously this was my problem. I will have to look more into this!

Comment: Joins can be done by listing the tables in the FROM clause and separating them with commas and then specifying the join syntax in the WHERE clause. if you forget to put the join conditions in you get a Cartesian product (every row of each table will be joined to every row of the other tables so you'll get `(Table1 Rows) * (Table 2 Rows) * (Table 3 Rows)`) which is likely not what you want. By using the explicit JOIN syntax it is much easier to see if you forget the conditions for the join. Knowing the difference between an INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, and CROSS join is an important skill to have.